# Paperclip - Aws::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

LOADS of questions around this, but none of the answers seems to be resolving my issue.  I'm using Paperclip in a Rails 5.1 app, and on save, I get the Aws::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect `The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.` error.  Reading around, it seems the common answers is to ensure you set the region correctly if not using the AWS default.  However, despite trying a few approaches to this, I can't fix it.

**development.rb**

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    s3_host_name: 'https://*mybucketname*.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
  }
}
```

also tried `s3_host_name: 'https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'`

I have also tried adding this in:
**initializers/paperclip.rb**

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Not sure what else to try now...

Answer (score 2):

So it was a stupid error!

I had taken the region from the URL:

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/mybucket/?region=eu-west-1&tab=overview
```

When the bucket is actually created in EU (London) which is `eu-west-2`

I'll leave this here in case anyone makes this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your AWS_DEFAULT_REGION of environments. Not AWS_REGION! "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=" worked to me.